# Как можно сделать подобие фонарика у персонажа?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas, pixijs

Все что нашел эту запись на форуме http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/7003-creating-mask-that-cut-lightsprite-to-pixel-map-terrain/

Пробовал как то использовать маски, но получается только обрезать картинку по форме геометрической. 
http://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/demos/masking.js

Натолкните хотя бы на мысль как это можно сделать.

Сделал что то такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В примитивном варианте можно сделать полигон с градиентной полупрозрачной текстурой. Продвинутый вариант требует знания геометрии места, например, чтобы могли проходить "лучи" света.

Comment: не понимаю как в примитивном варианте получится рассеянный свет, так чтобы со спины было темнее чем спереди

Comment: наверное понял, что то типо такого http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/cnlKt, не совсем то что ожидал но можно попробовать